# (Pyrogram/Telegrm bot) Russian words are not displayed correctly in Telegram

Tags: python, utf-8, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I made a word randomizer which works with txt file of words. But the bot send messages in wrong coding and i receive "РѕР±СЂСЏРґРЅРёРє" when it should be "обрядник". How to fix that?

The code:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\russian_nouns.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

@bot.on_message(filters.command('rng') & filters.private)
def command(bot, message):
    word = random.choice(lines)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, word)
```

Comment: Does the text file have UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, it's UTF-8

Comment: A simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'обрядник'.encode( 'utf-8' ).decode( 'cp1251' )` returns `'РѕР±СЂСЏРґРЅРёРє'`

Comment: Open the file with `encoding='utf8'` or better yet `encoding='utf-8-sig'` which will remove a BOM if present (likely on Windows).